# finding $c$ and $g$ at $x=a \sin b(t-c)+d$ and $y=e \sin f(t-g)+h$

Tags: trigonometry

The path of a fast-moving particle traces a circle with equation

$(x+7)^2+(y-5)^2=36$

It starts at point $(-1,5)$, moves clockwise, and passes the point $(-7,11)$ for the first time after traveling $6$ microseconds. Where is the particle after traveling $15$ microseconds?

Comment: I don’t think I understand your question… this parameterization of $x$ and $y$ is an ellipse anyway.

Comment: Can I add the problem which this question came from?

Comment: Sure. In fact, you should, since more context is always appreciated on  here.

Comment: I see. It makes much more sense now. But the premise of your original question seems to be incorrect since the phase shift is generally independent of the other variables. (By the way, $h$ is overloaded here)

Comment: My apologies. I'll edit this. Thank you.